# $9$ Vertices Each with $\deg(v_i)=3$

Tags: graph-theory

Can nine vertices be connected so that only three edges are incident upon all of them

Comment: How many ends of edges would such a graph have? How many ends does a single edge have? How many edges would therefore such a graph have?

Comment: Hint: Handshaking lemma.

Comment: $27$ edges... For each edge is $2$ vertices...

Comment: @Trancot: Really 27 edges? How many edges has a graph of 2 vertices, each of which has degree 1?

Comment: I'm OK, what a blunder... Yeah, sorry...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $V$ be the number of vertices, and $E$  the number of edges. If each vertex has degree $3$, then $3V=2E$.